# How to force initial data into an instanciated django ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form instanciated as such:

```
user = get_user_model().get(...)
f = forms.UserForm(instance=user, initial={"username":"whatever"})
```

But when rendered, the initial data isn't displayed, data contained in the user model seems to have a priority.

How do I force the initial data to appear in the form regardless of what's written in the  model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `user` instance before passing it to the form. The data will not be saved unless you call `user.save()` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, the idea worked. I didn't say this in my initial post for simplicity's sake but UserForm is actually a form which also edits profile attributes. However I can set them using user.get_profile().attribute = "whatever" and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old and I don't know if this is exactly what you were asking for, but this might help to someone else:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['initial'] = {'username': 'whatever'}  # Override instance initial
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```